# How to fetch user data from cloud firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uilabel

Could someone help me with retrieving the "firstname" data off my collection in firebase. I want to display the user name on the user profile to a UILable called "nameLable", but I'm not sure how?

I want each user to be able to see their name on the profile page if anyone can help! I'm using cloud firestore.

[image: Firebase collection]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to get the first name of every user in the document list.

```
func getName(Completion: @escaping((String) -> ())) {
    let collectionRefernce:CollectionReference!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    collectionRefernce = db.collection("members")
    collectionRefernce.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error is \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                guard let myData = document.data() else { return }
                let firstname = myData["firstName"] as? String ?? "No Name Found"
                Completion(firstname)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will retrieve `firstname` of every user. To call the function:

```
getName{ (name) in
    label.text = name
  }
```

In case you want to retrieve the firstName of the currently logged in user, use the code below

```
let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
 func getName(Completion: @escaping((String) -> ())) {
    let DocRefernce:DocumentReference!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    DocRefernce = db.collection("members").document(id)
    DocRefernce.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = docSnapshot, snapshot.exists else { return }
            guard let data = snapshot.data() else { return }
            let firstname = data["firstName"] as? String ?? "No name"
            Completion(firstname)
        }
    }

}
```

Then call it in `viewDidLoad` like this

```
getName{ (name) in
  label.text = name
 }
```

Comment: @Zack, my Pleasure! Kindly mark my answer . I ll appreciate that!

Comment: I tried but it said this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: There is '✓' sign on my answer.Just check it and it will turn green.